# "fo:page-sequence" is not a valid child of "fo:block". Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to change the page-sequence whenever the template matches table. I use wide tables which can't fit to A4 and therefore need to put the page in the landscape.

```
        <xsl:message>Outputclass: <xsl:value-of select="@outputclass"/></xsl:message>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="{if (@outputclass = 'landscape') then 'landscape-sequence' else 'ditamap-body-sequence'}" xsl:use-attribute-sets="page-sequence.body">
                <xsl:call-template name="startPageNumbering"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="insertBodyStaticContents"/>
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:variable name="scale" as="xs:string?">
                        <xsl:call-template name="getTableScale"/>
                    </xsl:variable>

                    <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="table__container">
                        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="table">
                            <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
                            <xsl:if test="not(@id)">
                            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                <xsl:call-template name="get-id"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="exists($scale)">
                                <xsl:attribute name="font-size" select="concat($scale, '%')"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class,' ditaot-d/ditaval-startprop ')]" mode="outofline"/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class,' ditaot-d/ditaval-endprop ')]" mode="outofline"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </xsl:template>
```

Is there a way to change page-sequence like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could try the "Page Sequence Master Interleave (PSMI)" utility from Crane Softwrights (see https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/resources/psmi/)
2. If FOP supported page floats (see https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-float), then you could potentially have floated the landscape table to the next page.
3. If you were using AH Formatter, then you could use a nested `fo:page-sequence` (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-ext.html#fo.page-sequence)

Comment: Found a solution with nested fo:page-sequence. Thank you